Create New thread for sub task using completablefuture
I have a problem,
On Service class i have a @async method which call three method using CF,
Service 1 Method 1 t1
Service 2 Method 2 t2
Service 3 Method 3 t3
In method 1 I have complex logic around 5 methods,
I want to do parallel tasking inside this like below
T1.1
T1.2
T1.3
....
First three thread I am able to do but not able to do parallel sub tasking within a method
Some basic example or solution I am looking

Hello and welcome! Can you copy-paste a bit of what you've tried yet?

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do and where/why you're failing? Are you using CompletableFuture directly or just via @Async? Do you want service calls and calls within a service to be parallel, is that what you're describing? Did you try splitting the service so that the "internal" calls that should be done in parallel are in another service? Or alternatively, did you try and spawn your own CompletableFuture instances, e.g. via the supplyAsync() method?

Likely your T1 could simply launch an ExecutorService in try-with-resources syntax, and submit the five tasks. But you’ve not provided enough detail to know definitively.
